# Finding the limiting distribution of $X^n_{(0)}$

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

I'm quite confused about how to find a limiting distribution if you're given a minimum order statistic from a random sample.  If you can perhaps explain the general steps and theory with this example that would be great.

Let $(X_1,...X_n)$ be a random sample from uniform(0,1).  Let $X^n_{(0)}$ be the minimal order statistic for this random sample.  What is the limiting distribution of $X^n_{(0)}$ as n tends to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the minimum is bigger than a certain value is the probability that each variable is bigger than this value. In other words:

$P(\min(X_1,...,X_n)>x)=P\Big(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n\{X_i>x\}\Big)=P(X>x)^n=(1-x)^n.$

As $n$ tends to infinity, the probability of the minimum being bigger than $0$ tends to $0$. Since the probability of being smaller than $0$ is also $0$, we can conclude that as $n$ tends to infinity, $X_{(0)}^n$ will become $0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Moreover, from this simple formula one can derive a sharper asymptotic result: $n X_{(0)}^n$ converges weakly to an exponentially distributed random variable.